# After every require_once it's adding a blank text element followed by 1

Tags: php, apache, byte-order-mark

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>**********</title>

        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 
            // top navigation
            require_once("require/top_navigation.php");
            // header
            require_once("require/header.php");
            // main
            require_once("require/main.php");

        ?>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>



<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=411386782258918&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

    </body>
</html>
...
```

I haven't done much direct php for a while, but when I seem to use the require_once it adds a blank text element followed by 1.  I've looked all over google and everyone that I've come across says it's because of BOM.  So I checked on the editor that I use 'Visual Studio Code', and it's not enabled, by default it's UTF-8 without BOM.

The apache software is Xampp.

Comment: What are the contents of included files, at least one of them?

Comment: "_a blank text element_" You mean like a `textarea` or `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Sorry to everyone, but I've fixed it. I found out that in some of the required files, there where other required sections that I used echo require_once, and that was where my mistake was.  Thank you to u_mulder for asking for the content which made me spot the error.